# How to Make Live Update for Android and IOS using Xamarin forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I have create mobile application using Xamarin forms and released application on Android and Iphone. Now I want to add some more feature in mobile app and send Update to exiting customer who already installed my app.
Please help me how to make Update existing app with new feature using Xamarin forms.

Comment: AFAIK this isn't something that Xamarin implements. google `Android in-app updates` and `iOS in-app updates` to find out what each platform's OS offers. If you find a solution for a platform, you'll add that code to the corresponding project. E.g. project `YourApp.iOS` or `YourApp.Android`. (You may have to translate any suggested code from java or whatever language to c#, but that is fairly straightforward.)

Comment: is your app distributed through the app store?  Then that is how your users will receive updates.  There are plugins you can use to notify users a new version exists, but they have to choose to install them

Comment: you can try appcenter  https://appcenter.ms/